# Comparing values in one column to values in a column in a second dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series, data-analysis

I have 2 `dataframes`, each of the `dataframe` has a `RegionName` column. I would like to create a new column that will has the value 'true' if the `RegionName` in `dataframe` A appears under `RegionName` in `dataframe` B.

I have written a lambda function that attempts to do this but returns false for all items in my `dataframe` (which is not the case). I have also attempted to use `np.where()` but to no avail

```
housing = convert_housing_data_to_quarters()
housing = housing.iloc[:,[34,35,36,37]]
university = get_list_of_university_towns()
housing = housing.reset_index()
housing['University City'] = housing.apply(lambda x: x['RegionName'] in university['RegionName'], axis=1)
```

This is my attempt at using `np.where()`

```
housing['University City'] = np.where(housing['RegionName'] == university['RegionName'](axis=1),'true','false')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas series have dictionary-like properties. Consider the following:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index=[10, 11, 12, 13])

'a' in s  # False
10 in s   # True
```

So you are in fact checking for existence in a series **index** rather than series **values**. In addition, `apply` + `lambda` is an inefficient, Python-level loop.

With Pandas you should look to **vectorise** operations, e.g. via [`pd.Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), which implicitly uses values. In addition, it will likely be efficient to make your comparison series unique first:

```
unique_vals = university['RegionName'].unique()
housing['University City'] = housing['RegionName'].isin(unique_vals)
```

This creates a Boolean series. If `0` / `1` is a requirement, you can then convert to `int`:

```
housing['University City'] = housing['University City'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for compare by multiple values of column of another `DataFrame` for boolean mask:

```
mask = housing['RegionName'].isin(university['RegionName'])
housing['University City'] = mask
#if need True, False to 1,0 mapping
#housing['University City'] = mask.astype(int)
```

Another solution is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) what is better if want create new values by mask:

```
housing['University City'] = np.where(mask, 'match', 'no match')
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the fellowing code, i make it for you as a tutorial ;)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

region_names = ["region_a", "region_b", "region_c", "region_d", "region_e", 
"region_f", "region_g", "region_h"]

# Generate 100 random university names
univ_names = ["univ-%s"%i for i in range(100)]

# Select 100 random university regions from region_names
univ_regions = [region_name[np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(region_names))] for i     
in range(len(univ_names))]

# make a universities DataFrame >> DataFrame1
universities = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(univ_names, univ_regions)), columns=    
["univ_name", "univ_region"])

# Now, you select the half number of regions, to make comparaison >> DataFrame2
regions =pd.DataFrame(data=[region_names[np.random.randint(low=0,     
high=len(region_names))] for i in range(len(region_names) // 2)], columns= 
["region_name"])

# get unique list of region name from DataFrame2
unique_regions = regions["region_name"].unique()

# Create the third column in DataFrame1 >> bool column
universities["isin_unique_regions"] = universities.univ_region.isin(unique_regions)
universities.head()
```